# Как сделать рамку с фотографией и текстом?

Tags: html, css

Вот шаблон сайта. Там где чёрная картинка- это картинка, а где text - это аналогично текст. Там есть рамки вот вопрос как это сделать через css и html?[image: Там есть рамки вот вопрос как это сделать через css и html?]

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, то, что пытались сделать самостоятельно. Вы же не хотите, чтобы за Вас всё делали?

Comment: Там есть рамка, и в этой рамке чёрный прямоугольник вот это я хочу сделать. Чёрный прямоугольник - это картинка

Comment: Ну так покажите сначала пример Вашего кода. Тогда обязательно поможем. Ваша задача решается за 2 минуты, но это не сайт выполнения задач на заказ. А сообщество помощи.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что у автора нет стремления самостоятельно разобраться в вопросе. Вопрос предоставлен как задача для решения. Даже не пытался, и не искал информацию в интернете.

Comment: @Sevastopol' Прошу прощения за оффтоп. Давно всё хотел спросить. Дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку на ЖЖ Вашей собаки )))

Comment: @Sevastopol' Понял ))) А то любопытство разбирало )

Answer (score 2):

Держите

```css
.title {
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.wrp {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

img {
  float: left;
  max-width: 200px;
}

span {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">name</div>
<div class="wrp"><img src="https://sun9-26.userapi.com/c5041/g12527588/a_91800fdd.jpg?ava=1"><span>text</span></div>
<div class="wrp"><img src="https://sun9-26.userapi.com/c5041/g12527588/a_91800fdd.jpg?ava=1"><span>text</span></div>
```